# Reactivate a Boostrap button with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, react-redux, bootstrapping

Hi I'm new React developer and I tried to do one thing very simple for you, I guess. I have a ButtonToolbar with 3 Buttons inside it. One of these buttons is disabled and I want to 'reactivate' it when I click on one of the two others button. It's simple or I need to use Redux to do that thing ?

Thanks in advance and sorry if I'm not clear, I give you my code just next.

```
var Alert = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){ // On initialise le state de nos composants
    return {clicked : "none" , nbClicked : 0 } //avec clicked a false et nbclick a 0
  },

  goodButton : function() {
    this.setState({clicked: "good"}) //On met a jour letat clicked
    this.setState({nbClicked: this.state.nbClicked+1}) //on augmente le nombre de fois que l'on a clique
    var object = this.refs.reset;
    object.disabled = false;
    //alert("You clicked the right button !"); //on affiche un message d'alert
  },

  wrongButton : function() {
    this.setState({clicked: "wrong"})
    this.setState({nbClicked: this.state.nbClicked-1})
    //alert("You clicked the WRONG button !");
  },


  resetButton : function() {
    this.setState({clicked: "none"}) //On met a jour letat clicked
    this.setState({nbClicked: 0}) //on augmente le nombre de fois que l'on a clique
    //alert("You clicked the right button !"); //on affiche un message d'alert
  },

  **render: function() {
    var msg = this.state.clicked; //On defini une variable msg pour laffichage du h2
    /*if(this.state.clicked){ //Son contenus varie suivant letat de clicked
      msg = 'clicked';
    }
    else{
      msg = 'uncliked';
    }*/
    const wellStyles = {maxWidth: 500,margin:'10 auto 10px'};

    var nbClick = this.state.nbClicked; //on recupere letat nbClicked que lon stock dans nbClick
    var disable = this.state.disable

    return (
            <div className='well' style={wellStyles}>
              <ButtonToolbar >

                <Button bsStyle="success" ref='good' onClick={this.goodButton}>
                    Click me !
                </Button>
                <Button bsStyle="danger" ref='wrong' onClick={this.wrongButton}>
                    You must not click me !
                </Button >
                <Button bsStyle="primary" ref='reset' disabled onClick={this.resetButton} >
                    Reset All States !
                </Button >

            </ButtonToolbar>
              <h2>You have clicked on the {msg} button and total clicks {nbClick}</h2>
          </div>
    );
  }
});**
```

Comment: Have you tried using `this.setState({clicked: "wrong", nbClicked: this.state.nbClicked-1})` instead of `this.setState({clicked: "wrong"});
    this.setState({nbClicked: this.state.nbClicked-1})`?

Comment: No, I never tried this method, I'll do it now :)